# Dojo NodeList-traverse - order of nodes returned

Tags: dojo

HTML

```
<div id="outer-container" class="container">
    <div id="inner-container" class="container">
        <div id="some-node"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-traverse"], function(query){
    console.log(query("#some-node").parents('.container'));
});
```

This will log an array with two DOM nodes - the one with the id "outer-container", and the one with the id "inner-container".

What I want to know is, is there a way to know in what order will parent nodes appear in the array returned? My testing showed that there isn't, but that doesn't make sense, the method goes through the DOM structure either upwards or downwards, right?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in JSFiddle and always got the same result:

`[div#inner-container.container, div#outer-container.container]`

If you really want to know what happens, check the "dojo/Nodelist-traverse" class in the Dojo source. 
This is what the "parents()" method does:

```
parents: function(/*String?*/ query){
    return this._getRelatedUniqueNodes(query, function(node, ary){
        var pary = [];
        while(node.parentNode){
            node = node.parentNode;
            pary.push(node);
        }
        return pary;
    }); // dojo/NodeList
}
```

I haven't gone through the "_getRelatedUniqueNodes" method, but it seems that the "closest" parent is added to the list first, following it's parent .... and so on. This is exactly what happened in my JSFiddle.

Comment: Yes, this example gives me the same result always, but my original code, which is much more complicated gives me the opposite result. Anyway I'll obviously need to dig through original code for this.